# Dynamic creation og Highcharts in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

I want to dynamically create charts in Angularjs with Highcharts. The Problem is, that Highcharts doesn't find the div to render it, although the have already been created.

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="test()">Test</button>
    <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  var names = ["ab", "cd", "de"];
  _.each(names, function(name) {
    $("#test").append("<div id='" + name + "'>");
  });
  $scope.test = function() {
    _.each(names, function(name) {
      var chart = {
        chart: {
          type: 'line',
          zoomType: 'x',
          spacingRight: 20,
          renderTo: "#" + name
        },
        title: {
          text: "name"
        },
        xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            month: '%e. %b',
            year: '%b'
          }
        },
        series: [{
          name: "test1",
          data: [
            [1, 2],
            [2, 3],
            [3, 3],
            [4, 2]
          ]
        }]
      }
      var chartObj = new Highcharts.Chart(chart);
    });
  }
}
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Phosphoros/bRNZV/2/

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation.

```
renderTo: String|Object
The HTML element where the chart will be rendered. If it is a string, the element by that id is used. The HTML element can also be passed by direct reference.
```

You are passing the "#" when you shouldn't be.

Just for reference - you are using Angular in a way it was not meant to be used. You should never do DOM manipulation in controllers. The chart should be a directive.

Edit: Updated your fiddle to something more like how it should be: http://jsfiddle.net/bRNZV/4/

Comment: I am absolutly about my stupidity. I read the documentation. I know how to use renderTo. I DIDNT SAW THAT. Sorry :-[

Answer (score 0):

renderTo will not contain #.

```
 renderTo: "#" + name
```

Replace to:

```
renderTo: name
```

SEE [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RvdW7/)